# Find items matching a dynamic path in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I know I can run a mongo query for something like `db.getCollection('mycollection').find({"user.email": "foobar@gmail.com"})`

However, the property I want to search for is underneath a dynamic key, so I don't know the full path of the property. The path goes like:
`fruits.qjCPnijzwqwu4bsqo.apples.skin.color` where the second item is an id of a different property.

I want to do a search for all items that have a color of `red`. Using pseudo code, I would write a query like this:
`db.getCollection('mycollection').find({"fruits.*.apples.skin.color": "red"})`

Is there a way to do that with Mongo?

Comment: "Probably."  Please edit your question and include 2 or 3 examples of the documents that would (and perhaps also would *not*) be selected in the query.  This will make clear some of the nuances in the design.  Already we can see that values might be being used as keys which is general is a restrictive design.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { fruits: { $objectToArray: "$fruits" } } },
   { $match: { "fruits.v.apples.skin.color": 'red' } },
   { $set: { fruits: { $arrayToObject: "$fruits" } } }
])
```